# fixed headers for webgrid, asp.net mvc3 razor

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, layout, webgrid

i had an panel in my project in which there was an webgrid. There was an maximise functionality for the panel so i had given webgrid width and height as 100% as it varies in width and height. And i am displaying 20 rows in the webgrid and scroll appears fine... Now my requirement is my headers should be fixed and user can able to scroll the content.. I had refered various blogs. In some blogs there was given that we have to give fixed width for "th" and "td" elements but it not possible in my scenario( as i had given widths in %'s wise). For example

```
  grid.Column("EquipmentManfacturer", header: "Warranty Provider", style: "column5"),

 <style type="text/css">

.column5
 {
     width: 25%;
 }

</style>
```

And in some other blogs they had given to give css style for "th" elements as "display: block" But this does not solve my problem. Can any one please help me to find a solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have to make the table head a fixed position, limit the table's height and set overflow to "scroll".  To do this add the following CSS to your page:

```
table { display: inline-block; height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll; }
thead { position: fixed; margin-top: -30px; }
```

It will take a bit of tweaking to get the layout right.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My thead is fixed but the widths of the coulmns of the theade elements vary.. The th elements does not amtch with the correct td element in tbody...

Comment: @dbaseman, I just referred ur answer. and it works but when I scroll the page, The header is fixed though I am not viewing the table i.e. it is fixed on whole page. Can you help me why that is happening?

Comment: @djIT I think you should open a new question?  It's hard to say without knowing more context.

Comment: @dbaseman, Ok. Here is my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825678/how-to-make-headerthead-fix-in-webgrid